# Rename App and Widget Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, rename

I currently working on a App with a Widget, so i finished the work to get into the beta and want to use a Public TestFlight for that, but my project still got his silly development name that i figured out won't be the release name.

So i found this post http://rshankar.com/how-to-rename-project-in-xcode/ but this is not working for me i can't rename the Project if i click it/doubleclick nothing happens.

If i simply rename the Target (App and Widget) i run into a error message,

> error: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier.

```
    Embedded Binary Bundle Identifier:  de.fboulegue.LeagueOfLegendsWidget.LeagueOfLegendsStatWidget
    Parent App Bundle Identifier:       de.fboulegue.LOL-Widget
```

Is there anyway to rename my project ( App and Widget ) without recreating?

Answer (score 0):

Oki, just needed to change AppBundle -> Target -> App -> Info -> BundleName and for the Widget Info -> Bundle display Name